# Reading python packages from an external git repository

Tags: python, git

I have a project in Pythonlike with a structure like belwo:

```
Mypkg
|___init__.py
|__module1
|  |__init__.py
|  |__module1.py
|__main.py
```

Actualy, I would like to dispatch the development of module1 to a seprate person and he can work it on Git repo, Can I use the module1 each time from a git repo, Shoud I write a requirements.txt in my project?

Comment: you need a [setup.py](https://docs.python.org/3.7/distutils/setupscript.html) file

Comment: Can you give me an answer or more detailed explanations? I want to import them from a git repo..

Comment: the link i provided shows you how to create the file that you need in order to distribute your product on github so others can easily install it in their environment

Comment: It was answered in [31446542](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446542/importing-python-libraries-from-github)

Answer (score -1):

I believe @aws_apprentice's comment was suggesting that you could build module1 as a proper python package by writing a [setup.py](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) for it, then install that as a dependency of Mypkg.  But during early development you can just put one git repo in another and .gitignore it.

```
cd mypkg
git clone <https or ssh git thing>/module1
echo 'module1' >> .gitignore
git commit -am 'add module1 to gitignore'
```

then to update module1 from changes the other person pushed to git,

```
cd mypkg/module1
git pull
```